# How do I add two methods in java?

Tags: java

I have written a code like this:

```
public class method{
int p;
static void number1(){
    int x, y, z;
    x=2;
    y=2;
    z=x+y;
}
static void number2(){
    int x, y, z;
    x=3;
    y=2;
    z=x+y;
}
public static void main (String [] args){
    p=number1()+number2();
}}
```

So you can see what I want to do but I don't know the way to do this. I just tried that one but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks for the any help!

---

Final code is:

```
public class method{
static int p;
static int number1(){
    int x, y, z;
    x=2;
    y=2;
    z=x+y;
    return z;
}
static int number2(){
    int x, y, z;
    x=3;
    y=2;
    z=x+y;
    return z;
}
public static void main (String [] args){
    p=number2()+number1();
    System.out.println(p);
}}
```

Guys,
Thank you so much it worked very well.

Comment: Make them return an integer.

Comment: So how do I do it? Thanks for the fast reply by the way.

Comment: I added my answer below. Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it resolves your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to add the result `z` from each method:

```
static int number1(){
    int x, y, z;
    x=2;
    y=2;
    z=x+y;
    return z;
}
static int number2(){
    int x, y, z;
    x=3;
    y=2;
    z=x+y;
    return z;
}
```

You could simplify this though to a more generic method:

```
static int adder(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

public static void main (String [] args){
    p = adder(2, 2) + adder(3, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
static int number(int x, int y) {
     return x + y;
}

public static void main (String [] args){
    p=number(2, 2)+number(3, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `int` return `z` at these methods like this:

```
 static int number1(){
    int x, y, z ;
    x=2;
    y=2;
    z=x+y;
 return z;
 }  

static int number2(){
   int x, y, z;
   x=3;
   y=2;
   z=x+y;
  return z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your main method, you need both methods to return an integer. You first need to declare both methods as int rather than void. This tells the compiler that the method will give you a number when called, rather than nothing.

```
static int number1(){
    int x, y, z;
    x=2;
    y=2;
    z=x+y;
    return z;
}
static int number2(){
    int x, y, z;
    x=3;
    y=2;
    z=x+y;
    return z;
}
```

Inside your main method, both methods (number1, and number2) will give you 2 numbers that will be added.

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    p=number1()+number2();
  //p=4+5
}}
```

To make your program more dynamic, you should take x, and y as parameter to one addition function which can be used multiple times.

```
static int add(int x, int y){
    int z = x + y;
    return z;
}
```

With this function, inside your main, you can now write:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    p=add(2,2) + add(2,3);
    //Alternatively, you can write: p = add(add(2,2),add(2,3));
    //if you really understand what is happening when a function (aka method) 
    //returns an integer.

}}
```

Comment: This is virtually the same exact answer as to what I've already added.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Method {
    int p;
    static int number1(){
        int x = 2;
            int y = 2;
            return x+y;
    }

    static int number2(){
        int x = 3;
        int y = 2;
        return x+y;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){
        int p=number1()+number2();
    }
}
```